# submit form not working after anchor link

Tags: jquery, html, forms

My code

```js
$("#btnsearch").click(function () { 
    $("#frmsearch").submit();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="#">some where</a>
 <form  id="frmsearch"  >
  <input  type="button"     id="btnsearch"  value="search" />
 </form>
```

Submit form worked fine but if the user first click on tag `a` and then click on `btnsearch` then `submit` not worked?!why?

For example with this link `192.168.0.7/viewer/index.php?rdbTypeSanad=Melk&code=01011001100100` submit form worked but with this link `192.168.0.7/viewer/index.php?rdbTypeSanad=Melk&code=01011001100100#`(# added) submit form not worked!?

[Online Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/a7LacLts/3/)

Comment: Can you setup a http://jsfiddle.net which shows this behaviour? The `a` should have no effect on the `button`. Also - if you make the button `type="input"` then you won't need to use any JavaScript to make it submit the form, as it will do it automatically.

Comment: There's no way that the code in question would cause this behavior. Please post all of the relevant code.

Comment: for example with this link `192.168.0.7/viewer/index.php?rdbTypeSanad=Melk&code=01011001100100` submit form worked but with this link `192.168.0.7/viewer/index.php?rdbTypeSanad=Melk&code=01011001100100#` submit form not worked!?

Comment: Can you add more information that 'it didn't work'. What happened? Did you get an error? Server side or client side?

Comment: As @MrRobot has said, change `type="button"` to `type="submit"`. And if you want to handle the form being submitted, use `.submit()`

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan you mean `type="submit"`

Comment: @rybo111 Yep. I'm an idiot :)

Comment: really not worked  i create simple when # added to url then submit form not worked! https://jsfiddle.net/a7LacLts/1/

Comment: Well your fiddle does not incude jQuery...So that is a bug

Comment: Here's a corrected fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/barmar/a7LacLts/2/ It submits the form even after you click on the link.

Comment: Do you have any Javascript that's triggered when clicking on the link?

Comment: @Barmar Yes i have but in fiddle i have not js on link and this not worked!

Comment: I just tried your newest fiddle. It submits the form after I click on the link.

Comment: On your real page, the Javascript for the anchor is probably interfering. Please post more complete code.

Comment: @Barmar this code worked for you on jsfiddle? first click on link and then click on search button، form submitted for you?in my browser Firefox and Chrome form not submited

Comment: The form just reloads the same page, so it's hard to see that it's submitting. But if you open the Network tab of DevTools, you can see that it does.

Comment: As a side note, if `method` and `action` are not specified, they will default to `get` and `self` respectively. `self` in this case would be the current URL, with a `#` on the end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should specify `Method` and `Action` attributes in form element to be sure that browser can parse form correctly.

```
<a href="#">some where</a>
<form  id="frmsearch" action="http://google.com" method="get" target="_blank">
            <input  type="button"     id="btnsearch"  value="search" />
</form>
```

Comment: As a side note, if `method` and `action` are not specified, they will default to `get` and `self` respectively.

Answer (score 0):

Cancel the click event so the # is not added the the URL. I also prefer to call the submit on the DOM

```
$("#btnsearch").click(function (evt) {
    evt.preventDefault();
    $("#myForm")[0].submit();
});
```

Comment: But this code not worked why? i create simple when # added to url then submit form not worked!

Comment: @ashkufaraz The code hasn't worked because you're not telling the full story. If you can't replicate the problem on JSFiddle, then it's not this code you're showing us.